# replace column value from number to text

Tags: r

I have monthly column value in number

`df <- data.frame(Month= c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "1", "2", "3"))`

I want to convert this to: Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar

Can anyone help me with this please?

Thanking in advance for your time

Comment: `month.abb[as.integer(df$Month)]`. The `month.abb` is a base R constant. One unfortunate thing is that it is not locale-aware, so non-English months are not available via the same variable ... though it is rather easy to generate your own, since all it is is a `character` vector, length 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most elegant or programmatic solution, but you could replace all the values with the `mutate()` function from the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

df = mutate(df, Month = case_when(Month == "1" ~ "Jan",
                                  Month == "2" ~ "Feb",
                                  Month == "3" ~ "Mar",
                                  Month == "4" ~ "Apr",
                                  Month == "5" ~ "May",
                                  Month == "6" ~ "Jun",
                                  Month == "7" ~ "Jul",
                                  Month == "8" ~ "Aug",
                                  Month == "9" ~ "Sep",
                                  Month == "10" ~ "Oct",
                                  Month == "11" ~ "Nov",
                                  Month == "12" ~ "Dec")
```

You can find documentation for using `case_when()` here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html

An alternative programmatic solution based on the comment left by @r2evans to do this in one line using the built-in R object `month.abb`:

```
df = mutate(df, Month = month.abb[as.numeric(Month)])
```

Comment: I am curious: does this work with the month numbers being of type `character` and not `numeric` (like the column in the question)?

Comment: Jan, likely it does, since R is going to silently up-convert `"12" == 12` to `"12" == "12"`. I typically don't like relying on this (especially where floating-point `numeric` comparisons may be at play), and I prefer to be explicit with what I know class a variable holds. But that's just a bit paranoid/defensive programming :-)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback in the comments. I modified my answer to be explicit about the numbers being strings, and also added a line that can be used to do this programmatically in 1 line as outlined by @r2evans

Answer (score 0):

Very simple way would be to have a vector with the months. Then you can use the numbers of the months as vector indices (after coercing them to integers).

```r
Months <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

df <- data.frame(Month= c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "1", "2", "3"))
df$Month <- Months[as.integer(df$Month)]
df
#>    Month
#> 1    Jan
#> 2    Feb
#> 3    Mar
#> 4    Apr
#> 5    May
#> 6    Jun
#> 7    Jul
#> 8    Aug
#> 9    Sep
#> 10   Oct
#> 11   Nov
#> 12   Dec
#> 13   Jan
#> 14   Feb
#> 15   Mar
```

The same can be done with the built-in `R` constant `month.abb` instead of creating your own `Months` vector.

<sup>Created on 2021-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: or use `substr(month.name,1,3)`